# Torchlight 2 Reactivation

Tags: torchlight-2

Has anyone managed to successfully reactivate their copy of Torchlight 2, purchased from Runic Games' site, after changing their hardware (in my case, the motherboard)? If so, what are the steps I could take?

PS: The license reset tool is not working for me and Runic Games is not responding on the support ticket, forum and twitter account.

Comment: Support finally responded and I was provided with a Steam key upon request.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you purchased directly from the [Torchlight 2 website](http://www.torchlight2game.com/) and have your 16 character registration key on hand:

1. Make a backup of everything in your user folder (on Win7 thats `C:\Users\[userName]\My Documents\My Games\Runic Games\Torchlight 2)`
2. Wipe your TL2 install via `C:\Program Files\Runic Games\Torchlight 2\uninstall.exe`
3. Reinstall TL2 via the demo provided at [Torchlight 2 website](http://www.torchlight2game.com/)
4. Replace your user folder from the backup you had created
5. Run TL2 and enter your registration key

If you had purchased via Steam, uninstalling a game is not immediately obvious.  As such, here are instructions for uninstalling a game from Steam:

1. Go to your Steam Library where all your games are listed at left
2. Right click the game you want to uninstall
3. Select `Delete Local Content...`
4. Follow prompts

Comment: I believed I tried this as well. The key step is 2: how do you "wipe" the installation? Anyway, I've mentioned that Runic Games support has responded, but did not give any resolution. I requested a Steam key instead.

Comment: Glad to hear that Runic has helped you out.  Regardless, I've revised my answer to add some links and additional information for clarity, as well as instructions regarding how to uninstall a game from Steam.  Please note that all specified directories assume a standard installation on Windows 7; user mileage may vary.